# Get an Excel exception "Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range Class"

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I get this exception when I double click on one of the cells in excel through VSTO

My code is as follows:

```
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
Range range = worksheet.Range[entry.Key, System.Type.Missing];
range.NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY";
```

It works perfectly when i use a tab key or any arrow keys

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It will likely be because at that point when you double click the cell, the cell is in edit state, you cannot make changes to a cell/range when in edit state.

Can you not achieve what you want by using the Sheet Selection Event, which is fired whenever a selection on a sheet changes?

Note that already clicking on a cell that has focus does not fire this event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx

Answer (score -1):

> I get this exception when I double click on one of the cells in excel through VSTO

You get an exception in the code because Excel is in editing mode. Use the following code to determine the state programmatically:

```
Private Function IsEditing () As Boolean
    Dim cBars As Office.CommandBars = ExcelApp.CommandBars
    Dim result As Boolean = Not cBars.GetEnabledMso("FileNewDefault")
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cBars)
    Return result
End Function
```

See [How to check programmatically if the user is editing an Excel cell](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/03/23/excel-check-user-edit-cell/) for more information.